# React-native - error about unique key

Tags: react-native

Why do I still get the error about needing to have a unique key?
This.props.numbers is an array of numbers and they generate/display fine with the code below. I still, however, get the error: Each child in an array or an iterator should have a unique 'key' prop.

```
generateGrid() {
    return this.props.numbers.map((sq) =>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <Square key={sq} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }}>
          <Text>
            {sq}
          </Text>
        </Square>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React wants you to provide a key because it optimizes how it determines whether items have changed and wouldn't have to re-render everything. Just add a key like this:

```
generateGrid() {
    return this.props.numbers.map((sq, i) =>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={i} > //Here
        <Square key={sq} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }}>
          <Text>
            {sq}
          </Text>
        </Square>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks, it works. As you can see, I already had the key on the Square element, but it looks like it has to be on the most outer element, hasn't it?

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't see that. Yup it has to be on the outer element and I guess you can remove the 'i' and just use 'sq' if they're all unique elements too.

Comment: I don't think it's good idea in general to use index as key. It might work in your case. But if you need to insert or delete array elements then react-native might get confused because a new element with the same key nows shows different content. Use some value that has 1:1 mapping to the content.